# Send command in autohotkey sends also text from next command

Tags: autohotkey

I have a Autohotkey Script like the one below. When pressing <kbd>Cntrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>7</kbd> a little text snippet should be inserted using the clipboard. The problem is that **pressing <kbd>Cntrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>7</kbd> sends the text from the <kbd>Cntrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>7</kbd> Hotkey as well as that from the next command** (<kbd>Cntrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>7</kbd>) and I cannot figure out why or how to stop it - **what am I missing?**

```
^+7::
Clipboard = // XXXXXXX ---------------------`n// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
send, ^v 


^+8::SendInput {#} XXXXXXX ----------------------`n{#} ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

multiline hotkey rutines need to end with a return. Single line rutines does not.

```
^+7::
Clipboard = // XXXXXXX ----------------------`n// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
send, ^v 
return

^+8::SendInput {#} XXXXXXX ----------------------`n{#} ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

^+9::
msgbox ctrl+shift+9 was pressed.
return
```

As you can see in this example the script still stops the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> hotkey rutine from running the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> rutine.

But it is still a good practice :)